# Visual Basic - How to select cells from a certain column or return error

Tags: vba, email, excel, outlook

I have a function made that sends an email using Outlook if I click a button. It currently takes data from an cell then opens outlook then checks the text from that cell in the address book and sends mail.

I only want to be able to use an active cell in the Name column (e.g. column 2) and if the active cell is in any other column to return a an error message This is so for example the column with the department name isn't selected and an email it sent to an dept mailbox.

I need some sort of error checking like..IF the active cell is in COLUMN 2 then send mail, otherwise return message 'make sure selected cell is in name column'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using:

```
If Activecell.Column = 2 Then
    '~~> Send Email code goes here
Else
    Msgbox "Make sure selected cell is in name column"
End if
```

Comment: or `Exit Sub` just to stop the procedure

Comment: Both have it's repercussions. 1st one should be avoided and the 2nd one used judiciously :)

Comment: Would you say that is better?

Comment: Well, there is a better way... Mind if I edit your post?

Comment: Not at all - Feel free

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58867/discussion-between-tom-and-siddharth-rout).